# clarify convLSTM usage for regression

Tags: regression, lstm, deep-learning

I am trying to use keras and convLSTM layer to predict future weather data based on  previous weather radar pictures.

I use **i** timesteps i.e. i radar images as input data. In my diagram, I assume **i=3**.
These radar images go through a convLSTM keras layer.
The convLSTM layer parameters require an input shape of the form :
(batch_size, time, channels, image_height, image_width)

**question 1** : in keras, the convLSTM layer does not require a *timestep* argument. So I assume it infers the number of timesteps from the input_shape. Is my understanding correct ?

In my problem, I would like to predict **j** timesteps ahead. It is therefore my understanding that *time* parameter of input_shape should equal **i+j** and that I should pad my input data with "blank" radar images. Indeed, this seems the way to create a many to many convLSTM layer where I need to predict timesteps ahead. In my diagram I assumed **j=3** and therefore **i+j=6**

**question 2 :** is the above understanding regarding a convLSTM layer shape correct ?

The capacity of the convLSTM layer will be defined by the numbers of filters inside each LSTM cell i.e. by the *filters* parameter of the keras convLSTM layer. For the sake of discussion, let's assume that the number of filters is defined by **k**. Therefore the output of each LSTM cell will be **(batch_size, k, H, W)**
where H and W are computed according to the convolutional neural network stride **S** and padding **P** and filters dimensions **F** i.e.

H = image_height−F+2P/S+1

W = image_width−F+2P/S+1

The network structure would then be like this :
[image: networkStructure]

**Main question:** How should I use these outputs to perform the desired regression i.e. to predict **j** timesteps ahead weather data ?

There is the well-known picture of weather nowcasting :

[image: Weather nowcasting structure]

**but I can't understand how to implement this structure**. Furthermore, the structure does not make sense to me based on the knowledge I have with classical deep neural network and convolutional neural network.

if I were to implement this kind of structure in keras, I would use the code herebelow, based on the data structure discussed here above. I have no reason for the batch normalization apart that I saw this implementation [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py) . 
**Question 3** If someone knows why batch normalization is useful, I am all ears
As one can see, the proposed code stops after the second convLSTM layer as I don't know how to process the data to perform the regressions based on the features extracted by the convLSTM layers. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
# define Architecture
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, ConvLSTM2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, concatenate, Input, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras_applications

targetNb = 8 # need to predict eight time steps ahead
availableTimeSteps = 3 # number of timesteps i.e. radar images used to predict the next ones
toPredictTimeSteps = 3
totalTimeSteps = availableTimeSteps+toPredictTimeSteps

inputConvLSTM = Input(shape=((totalTimeSteps , channels, image_height, image_width))) # samples first dimension not necessary 
x = ConvLSTM2D(filters=32,  # in convLSTM, #filters defines the output space dimensions & the capacity of the network. Similar to #units in a LSTM
               kernel_size=(3,3), 
               strides=(1, 1), 
               padding='same' # no reason for this setting, just saw it on keras example
               return_sequences=True, # return_sequences defines if the output returns the last time step output or all the time steps)(inputConvLSTM)
               # given that the #timestep is not specified, one assumes the #timesteps
               # is implicitly defined by the input_shape 

x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = ConvLSTM2D(kernel_size=(3,3), 
               strides=(1, 1), 
               padding='same'
               return_sequences=True,
               name = 'finalConvLSTM')(x)

# HERE I AM STUCK 
# I do not know how to use the features of the convLSTM layers to make
# predictions. In a classical deep convolutional neural network I would use a flatten so something like : 

x = TimeDistributed(Flatten(), input_shape=(model.get_layer('finalConvLSTM').output_shape[1:]) 

# flatten each time step
# x shall have dimensions (samples, time, filters, output_row, output_col)
# where output_row and output_col are computed according to convolutional rules
# so the flatten() shall produce, for each time step, a output of dimensions
# (samples, time, filters*output_row*output_col)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to stress an important point: `ConvLSTM()` layers have been excluded from the new **TensorFlow 2.0**, which is largely based on Keras in models' specification.
It is substituted by `ConvLSTM2D()` layers, that take different arguments as input. (see docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D?version=stable)).
(An alternative is to manually create a combination of `Conv2D()` and `LSTM()` layers.)

That is to say that `ConvLSTM()` layers might disappear in the not-too-distant future, and that studying how `ConvLSTM2D()` layers work might be a good investment.

However, coming to your questions:

---

> in keras, the convLSTM layer does not require a timestep argument. So I assume it infers the number of timesteps from the input_shape. Is my understanding correct ?

When working with RNNs, you should specify the lenght of the input series (the number o ftimesteps) from within `input_shape`.

---

> is the above understanding regarding a convLSTM layer shape correct ?

I'm not sure I understood what you're asking here. What do you mean with:

*I should pad my input data with "blank" radar images. Indeed, this seems the way to create a many to many convLSTM layer where I need to predict timesteps ahead.*

?

---

> How should I use these outputs to perform the desired regression

You can predict:

- one value at a time, with one output node at the end of the model,
  and then iterate prediction
- many values at a time, with multiple
- output nodes use a seq2seq model, in which you predict a sequence of
  the same length of the input, but shifter forward of one o more steps

This is all up to your preferences/needs.

---

> why batch normalization is useful

It's very useful between Convolutional and Dense layers, it's a regularization technique that helps activation functions work as expected, and allows the model to better capture non-linearities. However, I don't recommend using with Recurrent architectures, since the distortion of the output time series would decrease model's quality. (Please keep in mind this is just a personal opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

> The convLSTM layer parameters require an input shape of the form : (batch_size, time, channels, image_height, image_width)
>
> question 1 : in keras, the convLSTM layer does not require a timestep argument. So I assume it infers the number of timesteps from the input_shape. Is my understanding correct?

The ConvLSTM layer in Keras does take a time argument. You've just stated the input shape in the line above which clearly has time as its second argument, so I'm a bit confused about your question here.

The ConvLSTM layer in Keras takes in a full sequence, performs the unrolling internally, and returns the final timestep's output (or an output for every timestep if `return_sequences=True`).

In reply to your second question: you have drawn a standard many-to-many RNN architecture, this is not what you want here. What you want is an encoder-decoder RNN architecture which will allow you to predict your $j$ timesteps ahead, where $j$ does not have to be equal to the input timesteps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a bit vague what's your output dimension. Is it the forecast of a single step (j-timestep ahead) or a vector of multi-steps?

Question1: I guess time should be similar to vanilla LSTM, which is the i in your case (I need to refer other work to confirm this).

Main question: I think this is similar to the question of how to solve regression by CNN (as your output of the ConvLSTM2D is 3- or 4-d data). You can either pass the output to a stacked LSTM, or to CNN-pooling and flattened to dense layers.